# Select "where clause" evaluation order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, performance, select

In Sql Server 2005 when I have multiple parameters do I have the guarantee that the evaluation order will **always** be from left to right?

Using an example:

> `select a from table where c=1 and d=2`

In this query if the "c=1" condition fails the "d=2" condition will never be evaluated?

PS- "c" is an integer indexed column, d is a large varchar and non indexable column that requires a full table scan

**update** I was trying to avoid performing two queries or conditional statements, I just need something like: if "c condition" fails there's a way to avoid performing the heavy "d condition", since it's not needed in my case.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are no guarantees for evaluation order. The optimizer will try to find the most efficient way to execute the query, using available information.

In your case, since c is indexed and d isn't, the optimizer should look into the index to find all rows that match the predicate on c, then retrieve those rows from the table data to evaluate the predicate on d.

However, if it determines that the index on c isn't very selective (although not in your example, a gender column is rarely usefully indexed), it may decide to do the table scan anyway.

To determine execution order, you should get an explain plan for your query. However, realize that that plan may change depending on what the optimizer thinks is the best query right now.

Comment: Although not explicit in my question the "search non-indexed column among the found items in the indexed column" issue was also in my mind. In my case it completely suits my needs, because querying the indexed column first will leave only a small amount of records to filter, which isn't an problem

Comment: Just remember my last sentence: the optimizer may choose a different query plan for each execution. There are ways to "pin" plans, and also to specify hints to the optimizer; I'm not familiar with how these work in MS-SQL.

Comment: The point of using a declarative language is that the system figures out the best execution plan for you.  Optimizers tend to do ok on this sort of thing with current stats; something called "eddies" can in theory work without stats at all - but they are a recent invention, and may not be in MS-SQL.

Comment: Can we claim that indexed columns will ALWAYS be evaluated first when compared to non-indexed columns?

Comment: @AnarKhalilov - no. Different databases will apply different optimization rules. Oracle, for example, can use column-level statistics to determine when an index will be sufficiently selective.

Comment: @kdgregory I actually meant SQL Server but forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server will generate an optimized plan for each statement it executes. You don't have to order your where clause to get that benefit. The only garuntee you have is that it will run statements in order so:

```
SELECT A FROM B WHERE C
SELECT D FROM E WHERE F
```

will run the first line before the second.

Comment: In other words: NO.  SQL Server will re-order your where conditions in what it thinks is fastest way.  If your where conditions have side-effects (perhaps via udf function calls) this could cause problems.

Comment: Putting UDFs in WHERE clauses can be disastrously slow.  We've more or less had to outlaw them the performance was so poor.

Comment: Orion, actually, no.. that's not guaranteed either

Comment: and @SquareCog! Even if guaranteed, there will be hardly any difference in performance.

Answer (score 3):

One way to control the evaluation order is with the CASE expression.

[Edit]

The popular opinion I was trying to express was:

> You cannot depend on expression evaluation order for things like
> “WHERE  OR “, since the optimizer might choose a plan
> that evaluates the second predicate before the first one. But
> order of evaluation of the expressions in a CASE statement is fixed,
> so you can depend on deterministic short circuit evaluation of a CASE
> statement.

It does get a bit more complicated than that as explained in the site below:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160218234802/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/bartd/archive/2011/03/03/don-t-depend-on-expression-short-circuiting-in-t-sql-not-even-with-case.aspx)

Comment: The linked page has been removed.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the execution plan of the query and determine what it's actually trying to do. I think the query engine of SQL Server is supposed to be doing this type of scanning and will intelligently translate it into operations. Like, if you do "expensive-op AND false", it will quickly evaluate to false.

From what I've learned, what you type is (and can be) different from what's actually executed. You're merely telling the server what type of results you expect. How it gets the answer does not correlate left-to-right of the code you provide.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be sure you can check the [Query Execution Plan](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/tips/query_execution_plan_analysis_p1.aspx). The Execution Plan that MSSQL builds/optimizes is smart enough to check the indexed column before a varchar column.

Answer (score 2):

Short-Circuit is done when the condition we are referencing only includes literals or constants. So for example lets say we have a table TableA which has column num with all positive numbers from 1 to 10 and then if i write this query.

Select num from TableA WHERE TableA.num < 0 AND 1/0 = 10.

It will result in error.

Is compiler smart enough to determine that my second clause is consists of constants so it should evaluate that before evaluating clause which requires any scan from table or index?

Answer (score 1):

The MS SQL Server query optimizer does short circuit, yes. Guaranteed.

Run this:

```
select 1 where 1 = 0 and 1 / 0 = 10
```

It will run just fine and not error even though you're dividing by zero because the query optimizer will short-circuit evaluate the where clause. This has implications for any where clause where you're "and"-ing and one of the and parts is a constant.

Comment: Sorry, I don't believe you are correct.  I think @kdgregory is correct in that there is no guarantee here.  The query optimizer will decide what is best.

Comment: It is definitely not guaranteed - I am dealing with a situation just like this right now, where I want a short-circuit to avoid evaluating expressions when the truth value is already known (given usual operator precedence), but that is not happening.

Comment: These two parts of the where clause are trivial expressions so the query optimizer is not bothering to reorder them. Try this one instead: 

select 1 where exists (select 'Any Rows?' from dbo.LargishTable) and 1 / 0 = 10

There are some thresholds based on the way the query optimizer generates execution plans that determine the evaluation order.