# SQL Server - Select between two number ranges in a varchar field with text and numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2000

I have a table with ranges of numbers from 0-2000000. I can use a between statement to get the records of things if I do a BETWEEN 50 AND 100. That works.

But the problem I'm running into is since this column is a varchar if there are any records with a something in the string as "1FD32", I can't select between it. SQL server can't convert the "BETWEEN 50 AND 100" because it is looking for an int. How can i get all the records between these ranges, and ignore any with letters in them?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables . . . Admittedly, it is almost a parenthetical comment on the documentation page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173545.aspx), but it does state:  "The order of evaluation of logical operators can vary depending on choices made by the query optimizer."  This is discussed more extensively on other sites, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484135/select-where-clause-evaluation-order.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to do a numeric comparison, the only way to guarantee no error is to use the `CASE` statement.  This is the only SQL statement that guarantees the order of valuation (when not used with aggregation functions).

So, here is code that will work:

```
select *
from t
where (case when isnumeric(col) = 1 then cast(col as bigint) end) between 20 and 100
```

Note that if your numbers contain decimal points, then you will want to use `DECIMAL` or `FLOAT` instead.