# SQL Server - identify successful where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help on T-SQL. I have a stored procedure in my SQL Server with query (sample) as below:

```
select mpid, empname, sal, phone, [e-mail]
from emp
where empid = @empid or empname = @empname or sal = @sal or phone = @phone
```

In the above sample query, I have four conditions in my where clause. When I run the query, I would get results if any of the conditions are matched with the input variables (ex: @empid,@empname etc).

My requirement now is to identify which of the where conditions got matched with the input data. I just need to know the *first* where condition that matched with the input values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modified Gordon Linoff Answer

```
Select  empId,EName,Sal,Phone,Match From
(select empId,EName,Sal,Phone,
    ((case when empId=@empId Then (CONVERT(VARCHAR,empId) +';'+ 'empId')
           when EName=@EName Then (CONVERT(VARCHAR,EName) +';'+ 'EName')
           when Sal=@Sal Then (CONVERT(VARCHAR,Sal) +';'+ 'Sal')
           when Phone=@Phone Then (CONVERT(VARCHAR,Phone) +';'+ 'Phone')
           else NULL end)) as Match
      from Employee e
     ) e
Where Match IS NOT NULL
```

Removed case statements for each columns as it will check conditions for each column irrespective of satisfied condition

Added only one case for all columns as `the control will return as soon as any one of the conditions` is successful.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with a `CASE` statement in your `SELECT`:

```
Select  empid, 
        empname, 
        sal,
        phone,
        [e-mail],
        Case 
            When empid = @empid     Then 'EmpId'
            When empname = @empname Then 'EmpName'
            When sal = @sal         Then 'Sal'
            When phone = @phone     Then 'Phone'
        End As MatchingColumn
From    emp
Where   empid = @empid 
    Or      empname = @empname  
    Or      sal = @sal 
    Or      phone = @phone
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a point. I have around 40 such columns. So, I don't want to write 'Case' statements :-(

Comment: You have 40 `Or` conditions?  I'd think the easiest way would be to have a `Case` for each of those conditions.  I'm not aware of an easier alternative to finding which of the `Or` statements matches first.

Comment: @Prawin I'm sorry but that should be the only way you can do that. Also, why would you need to know which one of the many conditions evaluates to true, other than debug purpose?

Comment: Basically, I need to show a message to the end user about the column by which the data got matched! 
(something like 'The Record got matched with your Emp Name' or 'The Record got matched with your Salary' etc..)

Comment: Solution does not determine, which exact condition formed result row. I mean, what if several 2 search field are equal?

Comment: @xacinay as per the question: `I just need to know the first where condition that matched with the input values.`

Comment: How will you see `1st where condition' for data `where 5 = @5 or 'John' = @'John'`- which of conditions was 1st?

Comment: @xacinay The first condition in the `Case` that comes back true is the one that gets set.  If they're in the exact order of the `Where` condition, the column will be the first condition that matched.

Comment: As [far as I know](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484135/select-where-clause-evaluation-order) there are no guarantees about actual execution order of where clause and hence the result 'MatchingColumn' either

Comment: @xacinay The case statement would determine which of the results matched first in the order provided.  Whether it actually evaluated those conditions in the /exact/ order of the where clause during execution or not is irrelevant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55207/discussion-between-xacinay-and-siyual).

Answer (score 2):

I would move the conditions into a subquery.  That way, you don't have to repeat them in the outer query:

```
Select  empid, empname, sal, phone, [e-mail],
        Matches
From (select e.*, 
             ((case when empid = @empid Then 'EmpId;' else '' end) +
              (case when empname = @empname Then 'EmpName;' else '' end) +
              (case when sal = @sal Then 'sal;' else '' end) +
              (case when phone = @phone Then 'phone;' else '' end) +
              . . .
             ) as Matches
      from emp e
     ) e
Where Matches <> '';
```

Note that this method returns all matching columns.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `CASE` approach can barely fit your requirements. Probably the most reliable way to  determine, which exact value matched is `UNION ALL`:

```
select empid, empname, sal, phone, [e-mail], MatchCol from
(
select empid, empname, sal, phone, [e-mail], 'empID' as MatchCol
from emp where empid = @empid 
union all
select mpid, empname, sal, phone, [e-mail], 'empname' as MatchCol
from empname = @empname 
...
)
```

and then filter out duplicates with distinct for example

Comment: This sounds like quite a lot of overhead though.  It would have to execute the same query for every column.

Comment: That's correct - perfomance overhead here is huge, but the result is totally relevant to question requirements.