# Moving IF EXISTS to the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, query-optimization

In this sample query (against a poorly-designed vendor database):

```
DECLARE @OrderNo AS CHAR(8) = LEFT(@FullOrderNo,8)

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Foo WHERE FullOrderNumber = @FullOrderNo)

    SELECT  Stuff
    FROM    Foo
    WHERE   X = 'Y'
            AND FullOrderNumber = @FullOrderNo

  ELSE

    SELECT  Stuff
    FROM    Foo
    WHERE   X = 'Y'
            AND OrderNumber = @OrderNo
```

Since the SELECTs and first portions of the WHERE clauses are identical, is there a way to safely combine the queries **while insuring that FullOrderNumber matches are checked first**? I saw that there are [no guarantees for WHERE clause evaluation order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484135/select-where-clause-evaluation-order).

Comment: `WHERE FullOrderNumber = @FullOrderNo OR OrderNumber = @OrderNo`

Comment: @M.Ali:  That will return `OrderNumber = @OrderNo` unwanted records when there are records where `FullOrderNumber = @FullOrderNo`

Comment: @M.Ali I only want to match on OrderNumber if there's no match on FullOrderNumber anywhere in the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write this as:

```
SELECT  Stuff
FROM    Foo
WHERE   X = 'Y' AND
        (FullOrderNumber = @FullOrderNo OR
         (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Foo WHERE FullOrderNumber = @FullOrderNo) and OrderNumber = @OrderNo) )
```

If you are looking for only one row, you can use `order by` for prioritization:

```
SELECT  TOP (1) Stuff
FROM    Foo
WHERE   X = 'Y' AND
        (FullOrderNumber = @FullOrderNo OR OrderNumber = @OrderNo)
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN FullOrderNumber = @FullOrderNo THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
```

Actually, even if there are duplicates, you can use `with ties` like this:

```
SELECT  TOP (1) WITH TIES Stuff
FROM    Foo
WHERE   X = 'Y' AND
        (FullOrderNumber = @FullOrderNo OR OrderNumber = @OrderNo)
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN FullOrderNumber = @FullOrderNo THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)
```

Comment: These examples may re-write the two statements as one; but they don't insure : `that FullOrderNumber matches are checked first`.  If there is an index on FullOrderNumber, but none on OrderNumber, it is possible that it may perform a full table scan (which presumably OP is trying to avoid with this requirement).

Comment: @Gerrat . . . I interpreted that as "full order numbers are returned first".  However, I'm not really sure what the OP means.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Thank you; to clarify, I would prefer to avoid table scans. If the original performs better I'll stick with that.

Comment: @TrueWill . . . `or` often results in table scans.  However, the size of the data and the selectivity of the first filter have a large impact on performance.

Comment: In the first SELECT in the answer, I think you want parentheses around the OR part of the expression. Otherwise it can return matches where  `X <> 'Y'`.