# SQL Server: How does this SQL statement work

Tags: sql-server

Please explain how this SQL statement selects all `column1` values.

So I have parameter values A, B, and *

If I pass `@brand = '*'` then this statement returns all values in `column1`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE (column1 = @brand OR @brand = '*')
```

I'm thinking, when `@brand = '*'` then it assigns `@brand` as `TRUE`, so whatever is in `column1` will be `true`, so that's why it returns all values in `column1`

If I pass `A` then it will only return `A` values, if `B` then `B` values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. It evaluates the clauses in your `WHERE` statement based on the easiest paths, sequentially.

So, because there is an `OR`, it first evaluates the `@brand ='*'` clause; if that yields `TRUE`, the `WHERE` clause is satisfied and no further comparisons are made.

If it yields `FALSE`, then it evaluates the other clause in the expression: `column1 = @brand`.

However, I should note that this is not the correct way to do it in SQL, because SQL Server does not guarantee short-circuiting nor the execution order of logical clauses. It just happens to work that way in your case, but it is not guaranteed. You should change the `WHERE` clause to look like this:

```
((@brand = '*') OR (@brand <> '*' AND column1 = @brand))
```

Comment: So when it first evaluates `@brand = '*'` as `TRUE`, how does it know to apply it to `column1`? (Since no further comparisons are made). I'm thinking it only sees `@brand = '*'` and not `column1 = @brand`

Comment: @sojim2 That is the point - it doesn't apply it to `column1`. In an `OR` clause, only one of the sides needs to be `TRUE` - so the only way that both clauses will run is if one or both of the statements is `FALSE`.

Comment: For an example, check out this (non-SQL) code: http://ideone.com/GmzhHU (I cannot give you such an example using SQL code, because SQL does not allow side effects inside expressions). Note how there is an `OR` based `if` statement (`||`), and note how only the first function executes. Because it yields `true`, the second one does not need to run. The program already knows that if the first one is true, the whole statement is true (1 or 0 = 1). This is called *short-circuiting* (although SQL Server doesn't exactly do short-circuiting the same way, but that is beyond the scope of this question).

Comment: @Ruslan, no, the order of evaluation is not guaranteed.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484135/select-where-clause-evaluation-order.  That being said, the logical result is as stated..

Comment: @DanGuzman Yes. He asked *why* it works that way, not whether it is the right way to do it. That's the reason I mentioned *(although SQL Server doesn't exactly do short-circuiting the same way, but that is beyond the scope of this question)* in my comment. But, I agree that I should have mentioned that the correct way to do something like this in SQL is `((@brand = '*') OR (@brand <> ='*' AND column1 = @brand))`; will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @sojim2 it doesn't... if the second part of the statement evaluates to true, it is as if there was no `where` statement at all. Think of it as literally getting replaced by `true` or `1=1`.

Comment: I get it now, it basically takes the where clause out and only the select statement. Great explanation and correct example provided. I tested it and it works great. There's an extra `=` next to `<>` btw

Comment: @sojim2 Awesome, glad the explanation helped! It is really a bit more complex than that, but this is a good start. The way the evaluation of the `WHERE` clause works is that the query planner executes the condition for each row in the potential result set, where it yields a `true` or `false` - signifying whether or not to include the row. This is the way it works if `@brand` does *not* equal `*`; however, if `@brand = '*'`, then the SQL Server query planner sees that the result of the evaluation is stable (meaning, it does not change based on the individual row), and as such - it just

Comment: optimizes it away entirely (and basically, each row automatically evaluates to `TRUE`). So, if the query returns 1000 results, it will not evaluate `@brand = '*'` 1000 times; the query optimizer is smart enough to only evaluate it once. But, if it is evaluating `@brand = column1`, then it will evaluate it separately for each row. But that's going a bit deep into the mechanics of it. Also, thanks for catching the typo! It is fixed :)

Comment: I don't understand why you propose to change the WHERE clause. I agree, an execution order is not guaranteed, but on the bottom line, the result will be the same.

Comment: And besides the execution order topic, we should sonsider the case that one of the arguments could be NULL.

Comment: @SQLPolice It technically might not be the same in some cases, although it should usually be the same. Nonetheless, better safe than sorry. Regarding `NULL`s, it is a design decision in the OP's stored proc, and not really a missed case. Maybe it is not possible for `@brand` to be `NULL` (but I agree that the case should still be handled in the stored proc).

Comment: well, if `column1` is a function, then the execution order might be important, because it could have side effect. The saying *"better safe then sorry"* is of course also fully okay. Sometimes, a developer has not the time to get a full insight, and then better add something unnecessary, but be safe. But still, software developers should seek to understand the exact proceddings. Computers are no magic black boxes. They are operating by exact rules.

Comment: @SQLPolice Yes, which is why I mentioned it. SQL Server actually does not guarantee that the `@brand = '*'` will be executed first. The query optimizer **should**, in most cases, run it first, because it is the cheaper operation of the 2, but there is a million things that influence the query optimizer and can change the outcomes without warning (also, software is software, and bugs exist; I've seen *really* weird behavior with SQL Server in the past on very large datasets). However, the core point was that unlike most other languages, SQL actually does not guarantee short circuiting.

Comment: The order of evaluation doesn't change the logical result.

Comment: @MartinSmith It would in OP's case. If `@brand` was set to `*`, and `column1 = @brand` was evaluated first, wouldn't it then search for rows that are equal to `*`, instead of short-circuiting out that condition altogether?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you were trying to say. Regarding performance this pattern is bad anyway as the plan compiled needs to work for any value of `@brand`. SQL server won't dynamically change the plan to be optimised for the param value unless you use option recompile.

Comment: I tried changing the order, and the result remains the same. Since SQL will look for the easiest path of the 2. @MartinSmith -- I agree that the design is bad in the first place, I would change it but the crystal report that this SP is for is so hairy, I didn't want to change the way it works.

Answer (score 1):

> How does this SQL statement work?

Are you asking about logically?

SQL uses three valued logic. Each individual predicate can evaluate as either true, false, or unknown.

You need to consider the truth table for `OR` in your example to see how to combine the predicates to get the overall result.

[image]

In the context of a `WHERE` clause the overall predicate must evaluate to `true` for the row to be returned in the result.

The truth table above shows that it is sufficient to know that either one of the predicates is true. So if the first one evaluates to true there is no need to evaluate the second. This is known as short circuit evaluation.

SQL Server does not guarantee either order of evaluation or that it will use short circuit evaluation.

**An example**

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (
  column1 VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO @Table
VALUES     ('brand1'),
            ('brand2'),
            ('brand3')

DECLARE @brand VARCHAR(50) = 'brand1'

SELECT *
FROM   @Table
WHERE  ( column1 = @brand
          OR @brand = '*' );
```

The execution plan shows the following

[image]

The entire table is scanned and the predicate evaluated on each row. SQL Server may or may not evaluate the conditions in the order shown and may or may not use short circuit evaluation. This information is not exposed to us.

A single row is returned - the first one.

[image]

**Efficiency**

The semantics of the query above are just

```
SELECT * 
FROM @Table 
WHERE column1= 'brand1'
```

This ought to be possible to evaluate with a simple lookup against the index supporting the primary key - not scanning the whole table.

From SQL Server 2008 onwards you can use the following

```
DECLARE @brand VARCHAR(50) = 'brand1'

SELECT * 
FROM @Table 
WHERE (column1 = @brand OR @brand = '*')
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

This recompiles the statement just before executing it and does not cache the execution plan. This means that the plan can take account of the specific value of `@brand` passed.

Now the comparison of `@brand = '*'` is done at compile time and determined to be false and the predicate simplified to `column1 = 'brand1'` - allowing an index seek to that specific value.

[image]