# Short circuit and NULL checking in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I've seen people often set stored procedure parameters as `= NULL` and then do something like this in WHERE:

```
where (MinLength IS NULL OR MinLength = 1)
```

How does this work? Does it short-circuit? As far as I've read, there's no guarantee in SQL Server that short-circuit will be done for OR/AND etc.

Comment: Why does your question mention parameters but then your example code doesn't use any? Did you mean to ask this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36230244/sql-server-how-does-this-sql-statement-work/36234886#36234886

Answer (score 0):

Sql server does not guarantee short-circuit, that's correct. However, in sql, comparing null values to any value (including other null values, unless ansi_nulls is off) will simply return false, so there is no problem with this where clause. 
It's equivalent to

```
WHERE ISNULL(MinLength, 0) = 1
```

and to

```
WHERE COALESCE(MinLength, 0) = 1
```

The point of writing in like this is to allow sql server to use indexes that might exists on the MinLength column (since when you are using functions on columns sql server can't use the indexes on these columns).